# Find missing periods in bulleted lists ONLY

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm looking for a macro that will search through a Word doc, find only the bulleted lists, and then find any line that doesn't end with a period ("^$^p").

I've found macros online that search for bulleted lists (for example, http://wordribbon.tips.net/T008259_Finding_Formatted_Bulleted_Paragraphs.html), but it only looks for one bullet at a time and I can't get my

```
With Selection.Find
.Text = "^$^p"
```

to fit into the code sample provided there.

Any ideas?
10X!

Comment: What do you mean by *it only looks for one bullet at a time*? You can still do a loop and apply the operation you want, no? You can also write a macro (I have one) to find those bulleted items that end with a normal character `(^$^p)` one after another

Comment: When you run the macro in (http://wordribbon.tips.net/T008259_Finding_Formatted_Bulleted_Paragraphs.html), it finds the first bullet instance only. To find the next one, you need to run the macro again, and so on. I tried a 'Do While... Loop', but it didn't work. What I need is a macro that will find the first bullet instance, check if it is missing a period ' ^$^p ', and then comment it ' Selection.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range
   Selection.TypeText Text:= _
 "If this is a full sentence, it must end with a period." '

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing your macro :)

Comment: Just do a Google search on the following terms and you'll turn up lots of code examples: Word Find Loop

Comment: @CindyMeister - I know how to write a macro that loops and finds words; my problem was that I didn't know how to have it look for words only under certain circumstances. If all of the bulleted lists had been in the (correct) BullList style, then it would've been easy - but the people who write the docs I review seem to have an aversion to using the correct styles (or any styles at all for that matter) :)

Answer (score 0):

It was an interesting problem, one I usually end up looking to solve visually (which is okay, since it forces me to review all my work). But here's a macro that will do the trick:

> Edited to include bullets within a table, and also to call with a range parameter. Some code was also added to show how to handle bullets within textboxes.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim txtShape As Shape

    '--- checks the whole document
    NoteMissingPeriodsInLists ActiveDocument.Range

    '--- loops through any/all textboxes
    For Each txtShape In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        NoteMissingPeriodsInLists txtShape.TextFrame.TextRange
    Next txtShape
End Sub

Sub NoteMissingPeriodsInLists(checkRange As Word.Range)
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim para As Word.Paragraph
    Dim bulletText As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim done As Boolean
    Dim warning As String

    warning = "If this is a full sentence, end it with a period."
    For Each para In checkRange.Paragraphs
        If (para.Range.ListFormat.ListType = wdListBullet) Or _
            (para.Range.ListFormat.ListType = wdListSimpleNumbering) Then
            bulletText = para.Range.Text
            i = Len(bulletText)
            done = False
            Do While Not done
                Select Case Asc(Mid(bulletText, i, 1))
                    Case 33, 46   'exclamation, period
                        '--- the bullet correctly ends, so get out
                        done = True
                    Case 34 To 45, 47 To 126
                        '--- the bullet does NOT end with a period, so make a note
                        If para.Range.StoryType = wdMainTextStory Then
                            '--- add note as a comment to the bullet in the main
                            '    text of the document
                            para.Range.Comments.Add para.Range, warning
                        Else
                            '--- finding bullets in other parts of the document
                            '    may be valid, but adding comments may be
                            '    problematic, e.g. textboxes. You'll have to
                            '    decide how to handle those situations.
                            MsgBox "Bulleted list item in textbox does not " & _
                                   "end with a period."
                        End If
                        done = True
                    Case 7, 10, 13, 32
                        '--- ends with a BEL (end of table cell marker), CR,
                        '    LF, or SP, so go backwards
                        i = i - 1
                End Select
            Loop
        End If
    Next para
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked a charm! I hadn't thought about the Select... Case clause. Only issue is that it doesn't find bullets in a table - how would I add that?

Comment: Hmmm. Another thing I just noticed. It only works when it's a standalone macro. When I include a Call to it in another macro, nothing happens.

Comment: @Yoel: try using ActiveDocument in place of ThisDocument for the second issue (calling from another macro). ThisDocument will always refer to the document in which the macro is saved. Or even better: change NoteMissingPeriodsInLists to accept a parameter - a Word.Document object - so that you can pass the document you're working with and not have to worry if the user changes documents during code execution.

Comment: I'm editing Peter's Answer with the correction for tables since he did the real work - he should get the points for the Answer. The problem the code runs into is that the end marker of a table cell contains the paragraph mark and Chr(7). So the macro starts looping and doesn't get out of that first table cell. Checking if the range is in a table and reducing the range to leave out the end-of-cell and paragraph characters lets the loop continue. (Note: the edit won't be visible until after it's been reviewed.)

Comment: Thanks for the edit and the check for the range being in a table. One of the special cases I didn't think of, thanks!

Comment: As an aside, how would I modify this for numbered lists? I tried 'wdListSimpleNumbering' but nothing happened.

Comment: You'll have to look at the exact type of numbering you're using. Temporarily insert a `debug.print para.Range.ListFormat.ListType` statement and lookup the list type enumeration to find out what it is.

Comment: I seem to be having a problem with this script. When I try to run it on a large document (>20 pages), it hangs and crashes. Can you or @CindyMeister contact me off-list? yoel dot strimling at ceva dot dsp dot com.